# writing numbers between 20-99 to words in java

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner in java and we were asked to create a program that reads whole numbers between 20 and 99 and writes the numbers as words. The program reports an out of range error if the number is greater than 99 or less than 20. The program stops when the user types -1.

so far I have this code and I'm not sure if nothing's wrong:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question1 {

   public static void numberToWord(int num, String val) {
            String ones[] = {" ", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", " FOUR", " FIVE", " SIX", " SEVEN", " EIGHT", " NINE", " TEN", " ELEVEN", " TWELVE", " THIRTEEN", " FOURTEEN", " FIFTEEN", " SIXTEEN", " SEVENTEEN", " EIGHTEEN", " NINETEEN"
            };
            String tens[] = {" ", " ", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FOURTY", "FIFTY", "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY"};
            if (num > 19) {
                System.out.print(tens[num / 10] + " " + ones[num % 10]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(ones[num]);
            }
            if (num > 0) {
                System.out.println(val);
            }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int number = 0;
      
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Please type a number between 20 and 99 OR type -1 to end: ");
         number = scanner.nextInt();
         
         while(number!=-1){
            if(number>=20 && number<=99){
               numberToWord((number % 100), " ");
            }
            else {
               System.out.print("Out of bounds. Try Again");
            }
               System.out.print("\nPlease type a number between 20 and 99 OR type -1 to end: ");
               number = scanner.nextInt();
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: if its runs with no errors - your code is fine). got any java errors?

Comment: this has nothing to do with javascript. Also, how can you not know if nothing is wrong? Have you tried actually running your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, there is only a small typo in word "FOURTY" (should be "FORTY"). I would also remove the unnecessary spaces from strings in arrays `ones` and `tens`. You insert one space here:

```
System.out.print(tens[num / 10] + " " + ones[num % 10]);
```

so the space characters in arrays are redundant.

```
String ones[] = {
    "", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", " FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN",
    "ELEVEN", "TWELVE", " THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN", "EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN"
};
String tens[] = {
    " ", " ", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FORTY", "FIFTY", "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY"
};
```

EDIT: If I was doing that assignment, I'd probably write the program like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {

    private static String ones[] = {
            "", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", " FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN",
            "ELEVEN", "TWELVE", " THIRTEEN", "FOURTEEN", "FIFTEEN", "SIXTEEN", "SEVENTEEN", "EIGHTEEN", "NINETEEN"
    };

    private static String tens[] = {
            " ", " ", "TWENTY", "THIRTY", "FORTY", "FIFTY", "SIXTY", "SEVENTY", "EIGHTY", "NINETY"
    };

    public static void numberToWord(int num, String val) {
        if (num > 19)
            System.out.print(tens[num / 10] + " " + ones[num % 10]);
        else
            System.out.print(ones[num]);

        if (num > 0)
            System.out.println(val);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("\nPlease type a number between 20 and 99 OR type -1 to end: ");
            number = scanner.nextInt();

            if (number == -1)
                break; // Leave the loop

            if (number >= 20 && number <= 99)
                numberToWord(number, " ");
            else
                System.out.print("Out of bounds. Try Again");
        }
    }

}
```

but there are only minor code style improvements in comparison to Your solution.

Good luck learning Java! :)